# Can the deleted post content still be viewed?

Tags: discussion

There was a question about how to draw this form of straight line x==ty+n, and a friend answered three different drawing methods. I'd like to see again that I haven't seen the post now.

Answer (score 2):

## Some people can

As stated in [Mathematica Stack Exchange > Help center > Privileges> Access to moderator tools](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools),  this is a **moderation privilege awarded at 10,000 reputation**, so this is not accessible for everyone. Your current reputation will not allow you to see deleted posts.

> ## Viewing deleted posts
>
> You now have privileged access to posts that
> have been removed, either by their authors, by users with access to
> moderator tools, by moderators, or by the system.
>
> [...]
>
> You also have a new search operator available to find your own deleted
> posts: deleted:1.

## Finding the post

Furthermore, you are not making it easy for anybody trying to help you, because you don't offer much information to find the deleted post for you. What was the title? When was posted or deleted?

## Justification to make it available

If the post was deleted, likely there was a good reason to not keep it on the site. It's not clear from your question that there is any justification to make this particular post available after deletion.

## Conclusion

I think the answer is no, considering the current circumstances you do not have access to the deleted post. Sorry.

If you want a more detailed explanation on how Deletion works who can undelete and so on, see [this answer on meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/269874)